# Mouseenter not works in jquery

Tags: jquery, hide, show, mouseenter

I have got this simple script and I cant figure why my div doesnt show when I hovering it.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $(".hidden").hide();
    $('.moje').mouseenter(function () {
        $(".hidden").show("fast");
    });
  });
```

You cant find whole setup here https://jsfiddle.net/xbs75yhq/1/

Answer (score 2):

`class="moje"` does not exist in your HTML!

try using `.main`

e,g,

```
 $(document).ready(function (){
    $(".hidden").hide();
    $('.main').mouseenter(function () {
        $(".hidden").show("fast");
    });
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/xbs75yhq/2/

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are not assiging a class of moje to your containing element, instead it has a class of `main`

For it to work change the following

```
$('.moje').mouseenter(function () { ...
```

To:

```
$('.main').mouseenter(function () { ...
```